# How to analyze on SonarLint just the code that has been modified and not the whole class?

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, code-analysis, sonarlint

Is there a way to analyse the last modification on specific Java class without analsing the whole class in SonarLint

Currently when open file or I save my modifications the whole class is analysed and this is not intresting when it comes to large class.

My goal is to analys last modification that are about to be commited.

I am using SonarLint with  SonarQube Server and this one contains configured the Quality Barriers which analyzes just the difference of the code committed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SonarLint won't support analysis last modifications according to [mailing group answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/XOg281ED-5w):

> We don't plan to introduce those kind of analysis properties in SonarLint. The goal of SonarLint is to simplify configuration and to work out of the box, because it has the advantage of being able to take a lot of configuration data directly from the IDE.

Question was similar:

> We want to restrict sonarlint alaysis only for the latest modified/added code.